# CiviCRM - Mosaico - Test window opens but buttons are not clickable?

Tags: mailing, mosaico, testing

Drupal - 9.3.9
CiviCRM - 5.47.4
Mosaico - 2.8 -> Attempted upgrade but ran into the issue being tracked on github, so downgraded back to 2.8.

When composing a CiviCRM mailing using Mosaico, no matter if it is a new mailing / editing an old one, the test buttons are all visible yet not clickable.  This issue started after moving from Drupal 7 -> Drupal 9.  The only "error" (warning) thrown is:

```
    page not found /libraries/civicrm/core/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js.map
```

This is, as far as I could tell, only a dev console related error, not an issue that would cause the issue of not being able to click the buttons.

I have been unable to find any related issues on the respective issue trackers, nor on SE / Google.

gif of clicking the "Preview as HTML", "Preview as Plain Text", and "Send Test" buttons:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOS5T.jpg

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
Upgraded to Mosaico 2.9, still having the same issue.

**Edit2:**
Updated CiviCRM to 5.47.4, no change.

Comment: only ever had them as not clickable due to something like Subject or one of the tokens missing. The latter should give a warning. Not sure the former does. but doubt that is your issue

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Great suggestion as usual, but unfortunately no dice.  There are no errors thrown, not in the console, nor logs.  I triple checked all tokens, the subject, etc.  This happens even on a blank, new email.

Comment: is it same issue with New Traditional Mailing?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Nope, it's pretty much only the popup window when using mosaico.

Comment: I'm having a related issue on both Mosacio and traditional mailing, where I get the same error warning listed above. If I create an empty file, it goes away but I'm still getting angular errors in the console debugger, e.g. Possibly unhandled rejection: {"error_code":0,"entity":"Mailing","action":"create","is_error":1,"error_message":"Mailing has not been saved, Content maybe out of date, please refresh the page and try again"} when I try to send the email. Drupal 9.4.0, CiviCRM 5.50.3.